# TSAN build for QEMU, can't find longjmp buf

Tags: build, qemu, thread-sanitizer

building QEMU with TSAN did not get any problem
but it get FATAL during start up

```
ThreadSanitizer: can't find longjmp buf
FATAL: ThreadSanitizer CHECK failed: ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors.cc:544 "((0)) != (0)" (0x0, 0x0)
    #0 <null> <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x891b4)
    #1 <null> <null> (libtsan.so.0+0xa74ae)
    #2 <null> <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x2b0b2)
    #3 siglongjmp <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x2cb64)
    #4 qemu_coroutine_switch util/coroutine-ucontext.c:221 (qemu-system-x86_64+0xc0bcbd)
    #5 qemu_aio_coroutine_enter util/qemu-coroutine.c:147 (qemu-system-x86_64+0xc089c7)
    #6 qemu_coroutine_enter util/qemu-coroutine.c:170 (qemu-system-x86_64+0xc08b5a)
...
    #23 main /root/qemu-4.2.0/vl.c:4436 (qemu-system-x86_64+0x5c92ec)
    #24 __libc_start_main <null> (libc.so.6+0x271e2)
    #25 _start <null> (qemu-system-x86_64+0x2c6b9d)
```

it looks like the known issue for TSAN, and --with-coroutine=gthread seems work in the past

but it was removed (https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9704545/)

i tried all ucontext and sigaltstack backend, but failed

my question is, does TSAN still work for current version ? (qemu 4.2.0)

Answer (score 2):

There is work in progress to add TSan support to QEMU, and it is not in any release yet.

Our work in progress branch is here: https://github.com/rf972/qemu/tree/tsan_v0.

It is worth mentioning that our WIP branch contains several important patches that we picked up from Emilio Cota in [this branch](https://github.com/cota/qemu/commits/tsan).

[This patch](https://github.com/rf972/qemu/commit/9efcaa1cf1cf717f6f8bf4b768c9030fd3169de3) seems related to your issue.  It modifies the same area you referenced above and brings in the support for fiber annotations for coroutine-ucontext.